# .ASP Do I need to compile?

Tags: asp-classic, compilation

I'm poking my head around ASP for work and I'm not sure how it works... I'm used to being able to create a HTML, PHP, ColdFusion page, put it on the webserver and execute it.

Do I need to compile ASP pages or is that just ASPX?

I just want to create an ASP page and put it on my web server to test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create an ASP or ASPX page and put it on the server to test.  The web server in all those cases (ColdFusion, PHP, ASP, ASP.NET) takes care of compiling the page when it's accessed.

In ASP, I believe it is compiled(/interpreted) every time you load it, where as in ASP.NET it's compiled on first access (which is slow) and the compiled version is available for the next page load.